# How to change the way h2o creates and saves temp files in R?

Tags: r, h2o, temp

When being used in R, h2o generates some temp files named Rtmp******. How can I stop h2o doing it? If such files are crucial, how to change the location where they are saved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The H2O `tmp` directory is set by your R env. See the output for `tempdir()`. You can modify it before launching h2o, by installing unixtools and running

```
install.packages("unixtools",,"http://rforge.net/",type="source")
unixtools::set.tempdir("/your/new/path")
```